# How to switch from using scenes to just using timeline with one scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, project

My partner and I are working on a project in which we must develop a simple game and also have two videos e.g. museum interface. We have built a home page(scene 1) which just contains an ENTER button, we then have a Menu page(Scene 2) which contains three buttons for Video 1, Video 2 and Game.

We have been told that we should not use scenes so we want to put both scenes on one timeline and also subsequent scenes. Is there a simple way to take the scene 2 and put it on the timeline of scene 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to manage the visibility of each of the pages.  Start the app with page1.visible = true and page2.visible = false.  When the user clicks the play button swap these values.  That way both pages are on the stage at the same time and you don't have to use scenes.

Depending on how complicated or how many pages you end up using you might want to look into MVC (Model/View/Controller) Architectural designs.  They handle multiple views well in any language.  Flash is different in that it has built in ways to handle the UI that can make it easy to do simple things, but as soon as it starts to get big, it doesn't scale well.